# Is it possible to code an animation into hardware?

Tags: video, integrated-circuit

First off, I am a total illiterate in electronics. (Well, I did my Electronics for my Computer Engineering degree but that seems ages ago)

I am considering creating a set of video displays playing a small loop of video in HD, as in a photo exhibition that instead of photos has HD video loops that look like photos but move ever so slightly, so you can only notice if you stare for a while.

In order to make this installation less power-comsuming and less bulky, I'd like to know if the animation can be "coded" to a chip or whatever that could fit in the same flat screen, so it would be just a screen with a power cord.

Thank you.

Comment: How long are the clips you want to play?

Comment: probably <30 sec, why is this relevant?

Comment: The longer the clip, the more storage you need. A very long clip may not fit on any existing Flash memory.

Comment: yes, I guess it would easily fit in a flash memory. I imagine also a good HW codec would be necessary though.

Answer (score 2):

Getting things to run fast enough for HD video is apt to be difficult, but if somewhat-cartoonish or lo-res video would be okay (e.g. 320x200 at 30 or 60fps) the hardware would probably not be overly difficult.  Standard video requires about 16,000 lines/second; if each line is 320 pixels and each pixel is one byte, that's 5,120,000 bytes/second to read out the data as it's being displayed.  I think an SD memory chip could do that.  If each frame were read twice, every second would require a little under 4 megabytes of data.  A 16GB chip could hold over an hour of uncompressed video in such a format.

If you want higher resolution video, you're probably going to either need much more complicated hardware, or a means of streaming data much faster.  One possible approach might be to use a bank of SD cards, wired in such a way that data can be read in parallel from all of them.  One conceptually-simple way of doing that would be to build three circuits, one for each of the three signals in component video, and have each circuit read off its own SD card.  If one used 4-bit data for each of the components, one could then display 4,096 colors at twice the pixel rate as one would otherwise have displayed 256 colors.

Answer (score 1):

Low-definition (but normal speed) video can be decoded by the chip in a hand-held mp3 player. (Without those devices my kids would barely survive a long ride in the car.) I am not exactly sure what you want (resolution, color depth, frame rate) but is sounds compareable. But such chips are generally special-purpose combinations of a CPU and some MP3-accelaration hardware, sold exclusively to manufacturers of cell phones, picture displayers, mp3 players, etc. But these days you can get remarkable computing power in a small PCB, with for example a 200 MHz snapdragon, or maybe you should consider a PC-on-a-PCB (so you can develop on a PC and then transfer to the small PCB).

So: yes, this is probably possbile, depending on your exact requirements, and available size and power. But it might be less easy to make a small number, unless you can use an existing PCB-level product.

Answer (score 1):

Building something to do this from scratch would be difficult to do with little knowledge of EE, so a (at least partially) ready rolled system would seem to be the way to go. To get started a microcontroller dev board e.g [PIC32](http://www.designspark.com/knowledge/detailed-review-graphics-pictail-plus-w32-display-kit) or something more sophisticated like the [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard) may be worth looking at.

There are digital photo screens out there with this already built in too. [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B0DGAY) is one (see user comments for mention of short video capabilty)